# RxJS 5: skipping socket feed while keeping latest values

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I've been struggling to come up with an Rx strategy for a particular situation. I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Basically, I have a socket feed that I would like to skip based on a boolean value. When the stream is skipping the socket, I need to keep a running buffer of the latest value sent from socket.

Once I am no longer skipping the socket events, then push down the stream the last value that was emitted when it was skipping, but only under another condition (bool), and re-start listen to socket events

So basically:

- Listen to socket feed
- `takeWhile(bool)`
- When start listening again, apply last values while skipping
  socket, if `reapply==true`

Didn't get far, but this is what I have:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
.skipWhile(()=>isSkipping)
.bufferWhileSkipping??
.applySkippedValuesAfterSkipping(ifisReapply)??
.subscribe(val=>console.log(val));
```

Perhaps `skipWhile` is not the right approach but was the only one that kind of made sense…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it similarly to the following (I'm assuming your `isSkipping` can be an Observable):

```
const isSkipping = new BehaviorSubject(false);

Observable.interval(100)
  .take(20)
  .window(isSkipping)
  .withLatestFrom(isSkipping)
  .switchMap(([observable, skipping]) => skipping
    ? observable.takeLast(1).map(val => 'last:' + val)
    : observable)
  .subscribe(console.log);

setTimeout(() => isSkipping.next(true), 500);
setTimeout(() => isSkipping.next(false), 1050);
setTimeout(() => isSkipping.next(true), 1500);
setTimeout(() => isSkipping.next(false), 1850);
```

Every time `isSkipping` emits a value the `window` operator creates a new Observable that just re-emits everything or chains the `.takeLast(1)` operator when skipping is set to `true`.

The example above prints the following output to the console:

```
0
1
2
3
last:9
10
11
12
13
last:16
17
18
19
```